# Launching of process on mac using Qt

Tags: qt, process

i am working on sample applications using QT on Mac and i found out problem with one of its API. I want to run process so i am using following function

QProcess::startDetached();

And i am passing program(location of exe )and argument list as parameter now problem is that if the application is allready running then the  this will create another process and runs it where as when i cross cheked with Windows its behavior is different in the sense that it does not start application which is allready running. can anyone help me how to fix the issue??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, it depends on the application properties. On window you can open multiple Doc files but cannot open Window Media player in two different (new) window.

So, First try opening a new application while its running. If its success, then it should work with QProcess .